# Do not switch to newly added Fragment in TabPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have TabPagerAdapter with 2 or 3 fragment depending on events. When I start activity from one of the fragments and return back to this fragment, there is added new fragment to the TabPagerAdapter and is causing that it is switched from actual fragment to this newly created one.

I do not want to switch to the newly added fragment, how to achieve this ?

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private static final int FRAGMENT_ACTUAL = 0;
private static final int FRAGMENT_CONTROL = 1; 
private static final int FRAGMENT_MORE = 2; 

private boolean mControlTabVisible = false;

private Context mContext;

public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
}

public void setControlTabVisibility(boolean visible) {
    if(mControlTabVisible != visible) {
        mControlTabVisible = visible;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case FRAGMENT_ACTUAL:
            return ActualFragment.newInstance();
        //case FRAGMENT_COMPARE: 
        //    break;
        case FRAGMENT_CONTROL:
            return  getCount() == 3 ?  new ControlFragment() : MoreFragment.newInstance();
        case FRAGMENT_MORE:
            return MoreFragment.newInstance();
    }

    return new Fragment();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mControlTabVisible ? 3 : 2 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `getCount()` of the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. so that number of tabs will be constant.

```
  @Override
  public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
  }
```

for more details [Click Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html)

Comment: but number of tabs is not constant. I need to add/remove one ddynamically.

Comment: Even though  the number of tabs is not constant, you need to return tabs count  in the adapter. For this you can maintain a list of Objects and return the size of the list.

Comment: Once post your activity code so that i can help you better.